# XCUITest pre-testing setup

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-automation, xcuitest, qtest

I need to do the pre-test config, one time setup before I run XCUITest (automation test) cases,

Example of pre-test setup: (This needs to be done once for test cycle, the output of below APIs is used in all test cases)

1. Fetching `qTest` access token
2. Fetching the `qTest` URLs from remote config file.

From docs I found that `testBundleWillStart` method of `XCTestObservation` protocol is ideal place to do pre-test setup.

But
`-testBundleWillStart` method is **not getting called or executed**,
all below listed methods of `XCTestObservation` are getting executed correctly.

1. `testSuiteWillStart`
2. `testCaseWillStart`
3. `testCaseDidFinish`
4. `testSuiteDidFinish`

I tried setting `Principal Class` in UITest `info.plist` but no luck, it shows following error

```
Test bundle Info.plist at /var/containers/Bundle/Application/BEAFB0C2-43D5-4C90-B50F-B1FF1A16BC23/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/Info.plist specified MyAppUItests.TestObserver for NSPrincipalClass, but no class matching that name was found.
```

How can I get the method `testBundleWillStart` executed?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you created the `TestObserver` class in your code base?

Comment: I figured out the problem already, The problem was with my project name having space, it's fixed now. @MikeCollins, refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67023389/3733561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue,
My project name had a space, so replacing the space with `_` worked.

**Info about my project:**

- My project name: `My App`
- My project test bundle name: `My-AppUITests`

**Working Solution:** (Replacing space with `_` character)

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>My_AppUITests.SOTestObserver</string>
```

Let me also share the things that seem right but still don't work:

**Non-working #1:**  (Replacing space with `-` character)

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>My-AppUITests.SOTestObserver</string> //Didn't work
```

**Non-working #2:**  (Replacing project name with `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` environment variable)

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME).SOTestObserver</string> //Didn't work
```

Comment: Oooh yeah don't use spaces for anything 

Comment: Thanks for adding the what doesn't work. Your post helped me realize hyphens must be replaced by underscores. I'm not sure this is documented anywhere else.